# Arch Linux - QEMU override System Manufacturer on Windows 10

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, arch-linux

I've fully virtualized a VM with windows 10 on QEMU and had to do *host-passthrough* in order for it to work.

Because there's no way to set SMBIOS to reflect the host, I want to know if there's any way to change the `System Manufacturer` key in my guest OS.

Comment: Exactly where in Windows do you expect this information to appear?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it shows when you run `msinfo32` or `dxdiag`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy to supply any SMBIOS information you like by adding it to your libvirt XML definition.

Here I have added a bunch of fake information:

```
  <sysinfo type="smbios">
    <bios>
      <entry name="vendor">Fake BIOS Vendor</entry>
      <entry name="version">Fake BIOS Version</entry>
    </bios>
    <system>
      <entry name="manufacturer">Fake Manufacturer</entry>
      <entry name="product">Fake Product</entry>
    </system>
  </sysinfo>
  <!-- other XML nodes -->
  <os>
    <!-- other XML nodes -->
    <smbios mode="sysinfo"/>
  </os>
```

The result of which is:

[image: Windows 10 Insider msinfo32]

Many items other than those shown above can be changed; see the [documentation](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#smbios-system-information) for complete details.

Comment: Well butter my butt and call me a biscuit, that was simpler than I thought! Thanks!